# Locus of $z$ satisfying $\arg \left(\frac{z-8}{z-2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, solution-verification, polar-coordinates, locus

> For a given complex number, $z$, find the locus of points on the Argand diagram such that
> $$\arg \left(\frac{z-8}{z-2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

This is my approach:
$$\arg(z-8)-\arg(z-2)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Suppose $z=x+iy$:
$$\arctan\frac{y}{x-8}-\arctan\frac{y}{x-2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
This is where I'm unsure I made a 'legal' move. I reasoned that if I take the tangent of both sides of the equation, I would end up with a fraction that must be undefined as $\tan\frac{\pi}{2}$ is undefined; hence the denominator of the fraction I obtain must be $0$:
$$\tan\left(\arctan\frac{y}{x-8}-\arctan\frac{y}{x-2}\right)=\frac{\frac{y}{x-8}-\frac{y}{x-2}}{1+\frac{y^2}{(x-8)(x-2)}}=\frac{y(x-2)-y(x-8)}{(x-8)(x-2)+y^2}$$
But this is undefined; hence
$$(x-8)(x-2)+y^2=0\implies (x-5)^2+y^2=9$$
so it appears that the required locus is a circle with centre at $(5,0)$ on the Argand diagram with radius $3$.

Is my reasoning fully acceptable throughout my solution?

Comment: $z=5-3i$ is on that circle, but is not in the locus...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\arg(f(z))=\pi /2$, that means that $\Re(f(z))=0$ and as well $0 < \Im (f(z))$: that's a more "sure" way to go.

The steps in detail are
$$
\eqalign{
  & \arg \left( {{{z - 8} \over {z - 2}}} \right) = {\pi  \over 2}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad
 \left\{ \matrix{
  {\mathop{\Re}\nolimits} \left( {{{z - 8} \over {z - 2}}} \right) = 0 \hfill \cr 
  0 < {\mathop{\Im}\nolimits} \left( {{{z - 8} \over {z - 2}}} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  z = x + i\,y \hfill \cr 
  {{z - 8} \over {z - 2}}\quad \left| {\;z \ne 2} \right.\quad  =  \hfill \cr 
   = {{x - 8 + i\,y} \over {x - 2 + i\,y}}
 = {{\left( {x - 8 + i\,y} \right)\left( {x - 2 - i\,y} \right)}
 \over {\left( {x - 2} \right)^{\,2}  + \,y^{\,2} }} =  \hfill \cr 
   = {{\left( {\left( {x - 8} \right)\left( {x - 2} \right) + \,y^{\,2} } \right) + i\,y\left( {x - 2 - x + 8} \right)}
 \over {\left( {x - 2} \right)^{\,2}  + \,y^{\,2} }}\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;x \ne 2 \hfill \cr 
  \;y \ne 0 \hfill \cr}  \right. \hfill \cr 
  0 = {\mathop{\Re}\nolimits} \left( {{{z - 8} \over {z - 2}}} \right)
 = \left( {x - 8} \right)\left( {x - 2} \right) + \,y^{\,2} \quad \left| \matrix{
  \;x \ne 2 \hfill \cr 
  \;y \ne 0 \hfill \cr}  \right. \hfill \cr 
  0 < {\mathop{\Im}\nolimits} \left( {{{z - 8} \over {z - 2}}} \right)
 = 6y\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;x \ne 2 \hfill \cr 
  \;y \ne 0 \hfill \cr}  \right. \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  z = x + i\,y \hfill \cr 
  0 = \left( {x - 5 - 3} \right)\left( {x - 5 + 3} \right) + \,y^{\,2}  =  \hfill \cr 
  \left( {x - 5} \right)^{\,2}  + \,y^{\,2}  - 9\quad \left| {\;0 < y} \right. \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  z = x + i\,y \hfill \cr 
  (x,y) \in circle(center\,(5,0),\,radius\,3)\; \wedge \;0 < y \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  \left| {z - 5} \right| = 3 \hfill \cr 
  0 < {\mathop{\Im}\nolimits} z = {\mathop{\Im}\nolimits} \left( {z - 5} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

The circle is the same as you found, but (specially in the complex field) you must be careful in justifying every step that you do

Comment: Ok, how exactly would I proceed using your approach?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: I added the detailed steps, let me know if something is unclear to you

Comment: That's very clear, thanks. One question though; where do you get the $6y$ from for the imaginary part of the expression (in the last line of the first large curly bracket you made)? What happened to the denominator, that is, $(x-2)^2+y^2$?

Comment: a) the $6$ comes from $iy(x-2-x+8) =iy6$   b) $ \Re(a/b)= 0 \; | 0<b=|z|^2 \in \mathbb R  \; \to \;  \Re a =0$ and $0 < \Im(a/b) \; | 0<b=|z|^2 \in \mathbb R  \; \to \;  0<\Im a $

Answer (score 2):

Here is perhaps a better approach. Note $\arg\left(\frac{z-8}{z-2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ implies

$$\frac{z-8}{z-2}=re^{i \frac{\pi}{2}}\implies 
 \frac{z-8}{z-2}= - \frac{\bar z-8}{\bar z-2}\implies |z|^2 -5(z+\bar z )+16=0
$$
which is $|z-5|^2=9$, or $|z-5|=3$, i.e. a circle of center $(5,0)$ and radius $3$.

Note that $z=\frac{8-i 2r }{1-i r} =\frac{(8+2r^2)+i 6r}{1+r^2}$, indicating a positive imaginary and the upper half circle.

Comment: $z=5-3i$ is on that circle, but is not in the locus...

Comment: @jjagmath - the locus is part of $|z-5|=3$. In fact, it is the upper half of the circle.

Comment: I know, but your answer suggested otherwise

Comment: @jjagmath - added clarification;  thx for noting

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What exactly are you doing when you use the conjugate of $z$ after using the exponential form?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent - if $ w= re^{i \frac\pi2}= i r$, $ \bar w = -i r$. Then, $w = -\bar w$

Comment: Ok. Shouldn't the conjugate sign go over the entire fraction? How could you apply it separately to the numerator and denominator? Did you use a standard fact?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent - just apply conjugate to each complex component in the expression, e.g. 
$$\overline{\frac{z-8}{z-2}}= \frac{\bar z-8}{\bar z-2}$$

Comment: How exactly does that work? I don;t see how you can apply the conjugate to each component separately, especially as it's  a fraction. Sorry for a probably dumb question.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent - it is a standard fact

Answer (score 1):

If $A(z_A),B(z_B),M(z_M)$ are distinct points in Argand plane, then $\arg \left(\frac{z_M-z_B}{z_M-z_A}\right)$ is an oriented angle between vectors $(\vec{AM},\vec{BM}).$

In the present case $z_M=z,z_A=2,z_B=8.$

$\arg \left(\frac{z-8}{z-2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ says that the vectors are orthogonal, and $M$ lies on an open semi-circle with diameter $AB.$
(It is the upper half of the circle with diameter $AB,$ without $A,B.$)